# Problems in elementary number theory and methods from physics

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, soft-question, physics, big-picture

I was wondering if there are intuitive "physical" arguments to solve problems from number theory (elementary number theory in particular, but also advanced topics).

To make an example, a proof of some equivalences about primes that uses concepts like energy, forces, or something of that kind.

Can you suggest some references on this subject (or make some examples yourself)?

Comment: See this  http://math.stackexchange.com/q/944988/442

Comment: I think it is hard to find application of number theory in physics. Of course its even harder to find applications of number theory in physic that can be solved by "physical" reasoning

Comment: Google "conformal field theory" + "number theory".

Comment: @miracle173 I think the question is to find applications of physics—or rather, physical thinking—in number theory.  This doesn't seem out of the question.

Comment: @O.L. Along similar lines, I think that one could find some interesting connections in the field of mirror symmetry, which is intimately connected both to string theory and to $p$-adic analysis (important in number theory).  But surely we can give a better answer than "Go write a Ph.D thesis on one of these topics."

Comment: @Slade Maybe one of the simplest concrete examples would be the [proof of the Jacobi triple product identity via the boson-fermion correspondence](http://jamshidi.weebly.com/uploads/1/4/1/9/14199818/combinatorial_physics_proof_of_jtp.pdf).

Comment: @O.L. I still hope there's a slightly simpler example, but wow, that's cool.  If you gave a brief summary of the approach, this would be an excellent answer.

Comment: Check these books: [1] M. Levi, *The Mathematical Mechanic. Using Physical Reasoning to Solve Problems*, Princeton University Press, Princeton NJ, 2009; [2] V. A. Uspenski, *Some applications of mechanics to mathematics*, Pergamon Press, New York, 1961, pp. 39-48.

Comment: In addition, there are two related questions on *Physics Stack Exchange*: [1](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/414/number-theory-in-physics) and [2](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/26856/examples-of-number-theory-showing-up-in-physics).

Comment: Really good! Thank you very much for the references.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A "physical" approach to a *possible* proof of the Riemann Hypothesis: [The Spectrum of Riemannium](http://www.americanscientist.org/issues/pub/the-spectrum-of-riemannium).

The idea: the zeros of $\zeta$ are "like" the energy levels of an atomic nucleus.

Comment: Thank you for the reference.